# Parse XML for a value in AutoHotKey?

Tags: xml, xpath, autohotkey

I am trying to get a value to be retrieved from an XML file. However, using the xpath script found **[HERE](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/16137-xpath-v3-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-xpath-syntax/)**. I cant seem to get it to work. This is where I am having problems:

```
xml := xpath_load("C:\Users\Will\Desktop\Hotkey\IsogenID.xml")
MsgBox % xml
```

The file is there, and the path is correct. However, the xpath_load function spits back the value of "0" into the xml variable. It is supposed to load the entire XML file so that it can be parsed later.

This is the XML file:

```
<itemLookup>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <typeID>37</typeID>
    <typeName>Isogen</typeName>
</itemLookup>
```

And I am trying to parse for the **37** located in the  field.

Any idea what could be going wrong or of another way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone on the autohotkey forums gave me the answer to the problem, so I figure I will post it here as well.

```
xmldata = ; replace with fileread as you already have done
(join`r`n
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<itemLookup>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <typeID>37</typeID>
    <typeName>Isogen</typeName>
</itemLookup>
)
doc := ComObjCreate("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
doc.async := false
doc.loadXML(xmldata)

DocNode := doc.selectSingleNode("//itemLookup/typeID")
DocText := DocNode.text
MsgBox %DocText%
```